# How would I write an if/else statement that checks for if a class has focus followed by an event listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with the class name ('myDiv') that is focusable. I want to write an if statement that checks for 2 conditions:

1. is the 'myDiv' element focused?
2. does the user hit a keydown event (ex: enter key)?

If these 2 conditions are met, I would like to fire an action such as a console log. What is a clean way of writing a statement like this?

```
<div tabindex="0" class="myDiv"> Fire a console log when I have focus and user hits enter key</div>
```

EDIT:

Here's what i've tried:

```
if (('.myDiv').is(':focus')) {
            $(document).keydown(function(event) {       
                   if (event.keyCode ===13) {
                       console.log('do something')
                   }   
                })  
        };
```

Comment: Can you show us the dirty way first? Where are you stuck?

Comment: none focusable div doesn't fire any keydown event. At least if what you mean is that the DIV is focusable, not any of its descendant. So basically, you just need to bind keydown event on this DIV. Now your question is quite unclear imho

Comment: what do you mean by "focusable" ? do we have to click on the div ? Or just hover it ? It's not clear...

Comment: you can get focus on the div natively by hitting the tab key

Comment: I tried to clear this up a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
//Set up event to listen for keydown
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    // Capture only if enter key is pressed and .myDiv has focus
    if (event.keyCode ===13 && $('.myDiv').is(':focus')) {
        console.log('do something');
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use focusin and focusout event handlers it should work ! In your focusin handler you have to listen for the keydown like you already did. In the focusout you can remove this listener ! Tell me if it helps ;)

It would be even better if you add the focusout listener when the div has been focused in. Then you can remove the focusout listener when the div is focused out. Thanks to that you never listen for a "big" event like always listening for keydown for example... I would do it this way I think... Here is a possible example on how to do it in pure JS :

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');

myDiv.addEventListener('focus', onDiv_focus);

function onDiv_focus(domEvent){
  // add a listener for keydown on the document
  document.addEventListener('keydown', onFocused_keydown);
  
  // add a listener for blur on div
  myDiv.addEventListener('blur', onDiv_blur);
}

function onFocused_keydown(domEvent){
  // Do something
  console.log("focused + keydown");
}

function onDiv_blur(domEvent){
  // remove listeners
  myDiv.removeEventListener('blur', onDiv_blur);
  document.removeEventListener('keydown', onFocused_keydown);
}
```

```html
<input/>
<div id="myDiv"  tabindex="0">Focusable div<div>
```